# Login error when using phpMyAdmin and MySQL from Bitnami on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I have been bashing my head against a wall for the past few hours to get this to work!
I can ssh to the instance running on aws. it appears to be the latest LAMP instance. 
In my browser I can go to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin/` 
When i try with no password i get "Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)"
When i try with password as "bitnami" i get "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

I have the port open in my security group for MySQL inbound

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The doco seems incorrect in that it states that the password is just `bitnami` however I found that the randomly generator application password was in fact the password for my root user.

Go to the ec2 console in AWS, right click your running instance and choose 'Get System Log'.  Scroll through to about the bottom and you'll see this:

```
 #########################################################################
 #                                                                       #
 #        Setting Bitnami application password to 'your password here'   #
 #                                                                       #
 #########################################################################
```

This is the password that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: take a look at the Bitnami phpMyAdmin documentation ['How to enable phpMyAdmin or phpPgAdmin to be accessed remotely?'](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/phpMyAdmin_and_phpPgAdmin#How_to_enable_phpMyAdmin_or_phpPgAdmin_to_be_accessed_remotely.3f)

Slightly longer answer: According to the [Bitnami MySQL documentation](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/MySQL#How_to_change_the_MySQL_root_password.3f), the root password is indeed `bitnami` but you cannot connect to MySQL except from localhost hence the need to do everything from the shell or create an ssh tunnel.

Comment: i have created a ssh tunnel and am forwarding
3307 to 127.0.01:3306
888 to 127.0.01:50
i can access the phpmyadmin page from the localhost (via tunnel) but still get errors

Answer (score -1):

you can set your root password with this command

```
mysqladmin -u root password '[PASSWORD]'
```